# regex help matching within a single string

Tags: regex

I have a string like the one below

```
foobar1.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ   foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-1b28aeb7 ID   i-ca36b066 hello2.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-797607d5 ID   i-de95660c helpme3.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ    foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-3100a4e3 your-welcom4.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ   foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-51e63fe1 ID   i-c1592476 regex-foobar.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ   foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-a78a1311 ID   i-5c5150ec cps-web-p-va-001-1455223867.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ    foo-region-1b AZ    foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-96153212 ID   i-c810aa53 yayme-75-help.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ  foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-3c96a4b8 ID   i-3d96a4b9 ID   i-3e96a4ba ID   i-548903cf ID   i-558903ce ID   i-568903cd yesno.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ  foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-6b87f4d8 ID   i-9d57e714 address.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ    foo-region-1b ID    i-be4c9322 thanks-you_all.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com AZ foo-region-1c AZ    foo-region-1d ID    i-247f9696 ID   i-a20e5427
```

and i am looking to write a regex line that will match only the items that end with foodomain.com, but encompass the entire strings below

```
foobar1.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
helpme3.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
hello2.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
your-welcom4.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
thanks-you_all.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
yesno.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
yayme-75-help.foo-region-1.foo.foodomain.com
```

and so on

I've tried differnt things like `foo.foodmain.com`, but it does not select the entire string.

I've tried `\b\.[a-zA-Z]\*\. foo.foodmain.com\ \b` and `\b \.[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]*\. foo.foodmain.com\ \b` and still doesn't work.

I also tried other options, but I cannot seem to get it to select only the string tired together with the `.` but ending with `foodomain.com`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try [`\S*foodomain\.com\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vS5kJ6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you just need to prepend the pattern with `\S*` matching 0+ characters other than whitespaces:

```
\S*foodomain\.com\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS5kJ6/1)

The `\b` (**[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**) at the end requires the `.com` to have a non-word char after it (or end of string).

Note that the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Comment: If the answer is turned out helpful, please consider upvoting it, too, since now you have upvoting privilege.